# jQuery expandable div with plus and minus icons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a simple accordion div that opens upwards. I have my accordion working nicely. But I now want to add plus and minus icons to the accordion.

I have it somewhat working below on codepen here.    http://codepen.io/Davabo/pen/jqzgxQ

HTML

```
<div class="accordion">
  <div class="info">test text here</div>
  <h3><span class="plus">+</span> More Info</h3>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var $accordionIO = $('.accordion h3');
$accordionIO.prev('div').hide();

$accordionIO.click(function() {
  $(this).prev('div').slideToggle();
});

$(".accordion h3").click(function() {
  //Inner 
  var jqInner = $(this).next();
  if (jqInner.is(":visible")) {
    jqInner.slideUp()
    $(this).find('.plus').html('+');
  } else

  {
    jqInner.slideDown()
    $(this).find('.plus').html('-');
  }
})
```

As you can see, the accordion works nicely, and i have my plus and minus icons somewhat working. The problem is that when the accordion is expanded, the icon turns into a minus like expected, but when the accordion is closed again, the icon remains a minus when it should have gone back to a plus.

Comment: var jqInner = $(this).next(); is wrong. So the referenced element is never visible. $(this) refers to H3 in this case, you need the info span.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you I'd handle this with CSS as much as I can.

In your css have this:

```
.accordion h3 .plus {
    content: "+";
}
.accordion h3 active .plus {
    content: "-";
}
```

Then in your jQuery, do this:

```
$(".accordion h3").click(function() {
  //Inner 
  var jqInner = $(this).next();
  jqInner.toggleClass("active");
  jqInner.toggleSlide();
})
```

Instead you can also create 2 spans for the '+' and the '-', and toggle their display property based on the 'active' class.

Answer (score 2):

Your code should be this:
[See codepen](http://codepen.io/yoeri/pen/eZMqbO)

```
      var $accordionIO = $('.accordion h3');
      $accordionIO.prev('div').hide();

      $(".accordion h3").click(function () {
          //Inner 
          var jqInner = $('.info', $(this).parent());
          if (jqInner.is(":visible"))
          {
              jqInner.slideUp()
              $(this).find('.plus').html('+');
          }

          else

          {
              jqInner.slideDown()
              $(this).find('.plus').html('-');
          }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the following changes:

**HTML** - Remove the span assign `.plus` to h3

```
   <h3 class="plus"> More Info</h3>
```

**CSS** - Add these two classes to represent the state of the accordion.

```
       .plus:before {
  content: '+';
}
       .minus:before {
  content: '-';
}
```

**jQuery** - Remove the two lines for slideup/down and use `$(this).toggleClass('plus minus')` after the slideup/down.

```
    $(".accordion h3").click(function () {
          //Inner 
          var jqInner = $(this).next();
          if (jqInner.is(":visible"))
          {
              jqInner.slideUp()

          }

          else

          {
              jqInner.slideDown()

          }
        $(this).toggleClass('plus minus');
    })
```

[**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/zer00ne/pen/zqWgmx?editors=1000)

**Snippet**

```js
 var $accordionIO = $('.accordion h3');
 $accordionIO.prev('div').hide();

 $accordionIO.click(function() {
   $(this).prev('div').slideToggle();
 });

 $(".accordion h3").click(function() {
   //Inner 
   var jqInner = $(this).next();
   if (jqInner.is(":visible")) {
     jqInner.slideUp()

   } else

   {
     jqInner.slideDown()

   }
   $(this).toggleClass('plus minus');
 })
```

```css
.info {
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 70%;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.plus:before {
  content: '+';
}
.minus:before {
  content: '-';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion">
  <div class="info">test text here</div>
  <h3 class="plus"> More Info</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

inside your code pan, condition `if(jqInner.is(":visible"))` is not working. every time you call function it moves to `else` part so it will not change `-` to `+`.

i have updated the code that working properly

```js
var $accordionIO = $('.accordion h3');
$accordionIO.prev('div').hide();
$accordionIO.click(function() {
  $(this).prev('div').slideToggle();
});
$(".accordion h3").click(function() {
  var jqInner = $(this).next();
  jqInner.slideToggle();
  var t = $(this).find('.plus').html();
  t == "+" ? $(this).find('.plus').html('-') : $(this).find('.plus').html('+');
})
```

```css
.info {
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 70%;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion">
  <div class="info">test text here</div>
  <h3><span class="plus">+</span> More Info</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="accordion">
 <div class="info">test text here</div>
  <h3><span class="plus">+</span> More Info</h3>
  <div class="info">test text here</div>
  <h3><span class="plus">+</span> More Info</h3>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
var $accordionIO = $('.accordion h3');
$accordionIO.prev('div').hide();
$accordionIO.click(function() {
  $(this).prev('div').slideToggle();
});
$(".accordion h3").click(function() {
  $('.info').slideUp();
  $('.plus').html('+');
  var jqInner = $(this).prev();
  jqInner.slideToggle();
  var icon1 = $(this).find('.plus').html();
  icon1 == "+" ? $(this).find('.plus').html('-') : $(this).find('.plus').html('+');
})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

According accordion functionality it should collapse other divs when one div is expanded. The expanded div will never collapse on clicking on it. The code works with same logic.